# Oracle query to get nested key value pair

Tags: sql, json, oracle, nested

I am trying to extract the key and value pair from a nested JSON in an Oracle database. The JSON is saved as a CLOB in my database.

I am unsuccessful in getting the key name from my query:

```
  select key_v, var_name, sub_q
  from sampletable,
  json_table (sample_json , '$'
  columns (key_v varchar2(36) path '$."result"."exportColumnMap"',
  nested path '$."result"."exportColumnMap".*'
  columns (var_name varchar2(24) path '$."question"',
           sub_q varchar2(36) path '$."choice"' 
            )))
 where var_name is not null;
```

Ideally the resulting table from the select statement ends up as

```
KEY_1, ANSWER1, QUESTION1
KEY_2, ANSWER2, QUESTION2
KEY_3, ANSWER3, QUESTION3
```

sample_json:

```
{"result": 
    "exportColumnMap": {
        "KEY_1": {
            "choice": "ANSWER1", 
            "question": "QUESTION1"
        }, 
        "KEY_2": {
            "choice": "ANSWER2", 
            "question": "QUESTION2"
        }, 
        "KEY_3": {
            "choice": "ANSWER3", 
            "question": "QUESTION3"
        }}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a couple things. First, your JSON is invalid. The top-level layout is "{KEY: KEY: {VALUE}}", when it should be "{KEY: { KEY: {VALUE} }}", like so:

```
{"result": 
    {"exportColumnMap": {
        "KEY_1": {
            "choice": "ANSWER1", 
            "question": "QUESTION1"
        }, 
        "KEY_2": {
            "choice": "ANSWER2", 
            "question": "QUESTION2"
        }, 
        "KEY_3": {
            "choice": "ANSWER3", 
            "question": "QUESTION3"
        }}}}
```

Second, your query looks pretty good, but unfortunately I don't really know of an easy way to retrieve JSON key names. Your `key_v` column retrieves the *value* of KEY_1, KEY2, etc, which look like `{"choice": "ANSWER1",...}`, not the key name of "KEY_1". It would be much easier to use an ordinality column, like this, and if you really need the column values to have "KEY_" in front of them, paste that in later on. Or change the structure of your JSON to store all of the values you want to retrieve as *values* instead of *key names*.

```
select key_v, var_name, sub_q
  from sampletable,
  json_table (sample_json , '$'
    columns (key_v FOR ORDINALITY,
      nested path '$."result"."exportColumnMap".*'
        columns (var_name varchar2(24) path '$."question"',
                sub_q varchar2(36) path '$."choice"' 
  )))
  where var_name is not null;
```

Output for this will look like:

```
1, ANSWER1, QUESTION1
2, ANSWER2, QUESTION2
3, ANSWER3, QUESTION3
```

Comment: Is there a way to return the actual key values, e.g. `KEY_1`, `KEY_2` instead of the number that is generated by `for ordinality`

Comment: Not easily, I think? The keys are like column names, they're hard to select without a data dictionary. It's been asked before, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424591/how-to-get-key-value-as-resultset-from-oracle-json-column-using-json-table

Comment: In 12c it's a little easier in PL/SQL; they added a JSON_OBJECT_T type with a `get_keys()` function, so you can get a list of the key names, but you'd still have to write your own function, since it can't be called from SQL.